# Camel and bulk insert

Tags: database, apache-camel, bulkinsert

I would like to read a CSV file, process rows and insert into a database several rows but I don't want insert one row at a time but several. Is it possible if yes how ? Thanks

Comment: Which database? What have you tried? Unlikely that this question will be answered in this state. At some point a file will need to be read one line at a time. You can thread it and do concurrent inserts. So you dont insert row by agonizing row.

Comment: I uses Mysql as database. I would like optimize my inserts and I have to do rows aggregations

Comment: Why don't you try to get it to work with a single row first..and then optimize to multiple rows?

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far. Also you should try getting a single row into database first, and then you can optimize the route to insert multiple rows at a time into the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The out-of-the-box database components either don't support batch inserts or are tricky to get sorted out. One approach I have had success with in the past is using a split+aggregator pattern and then passing it to a custom processor which does the insert using JPA.

Pseudo code:

```
from(file://inputfile.csv..)
.splitter(.. by line..)
.aggregate(.. by count ~ 50 or 100)
.to(customJpaProcessor)
```

Then in the custom processor, grab the GroupedExchange and loop over the rows, persist and after a certain number do the .commit()

[Camel Aggregator EIP](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html)

Comment: I solved my problem I used a processor to aggregate my data and to save my data. Thanks.

Comment: atoua glad to hear! Would you do me a favor and "accept" the answer? Thanks =)